# Apache Tomcat failed to start with SAXParserFactoryImpl not found

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, xerces

I'm trying to start Web application in Eclipse Apache Tomcat it failed with below error posted in gist.

Error:[complete Error link](https://gist.github.com/saravana2906/f8bca1b40a7cd04785354350d93d5000)

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:308)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
```

Below is pom file dependency related to xml , i have

```
 <dependency>
                            <groupId>xerces</groupId> 
                            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                            <version>2.4.0</version>
                            <scope>provided</scope>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                               <groupId>ibm</groupId>
                               <artifactId>xml4j</artifactId>
                                <version>2.0.15</version>
                         </dependency>
```

I tried various solutions , pasting xerces jar to jre/lib/endorsed folder , marking it as provided , refershing target directory nothing worked .

Comment: Try using apache xerces dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1

Comment: @JorgeCampos   , I'm working in migration of old project , latest jar fixed the issue . I will accept it as answer

Comment: Used xerces jar from apache instead of wso2 , https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1

Comment: Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment helped you out, I'm posting it as an answer.

Use Apache Xerces Dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xerces/xercesImpl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```